# Getting a Segfault on Close of a file

Tags: c++, linux, windows

I am getting this strange error. Only happens on linux which I need to have it work on that OS, but on windows works perfectly fine.

Happens only on `inFile.close();` Have tested this with a lot of `cout` statements.

Here is the function where it gets seg faulted at. (Element300 is a c style string that has 81 characters including the terminator. Also the file being read in is JAVA keywords so nothing is over 80 characters.)

Here is the function:

```
void HT300::fill300()
{
    Element300 readLine = "\0";
    Element300 tempLine = "\0";
    int hashedValue;
    int tempIndex = 0;
    int tempProbed = 0;
    int tempLineIndex = 0;
    int readLineIndex = 0;
    ifstream inFile;

    inFile.open("RWJAVA.DAT");

    if(!inFile)
    {
        cerr << "File not found: RWJAVA.DAT" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        while(!inFile.getline(readLine,MAX_SIZE,'\n').eof())
        {
            while(readLine[readLineIndex] == ' ')
            {
                readLineIndex++;
            }
            while(isalnum(readLine[readLineIndex]))
            {
                tempLine[tempLineIndex] = readLine[readLineIndex];
                tempLineIndex++;
                readLineIndex++;
            }
            tempLine[tempLineIndex] = '\0';


            hashedValue = hash300(tempLine);
            tempIndex = hashedValue;

            while(strcmp(theTable[tempIndex].reserved,tempLine) != 0 && strcmp(theTable[tempIndex].reserved, "\0") != 0)
            {
                tempProbed++;
                tempIndex += 3;

                if(tempIndex > MAX_TABLE)
                {
                    tempIndex = 0;
                }

            }
            if(strcmp(theTable[tempIndex].reserved,"\0") == 0)
            {
                strcpy(theTable[tempIndex].reserved,tempLine);
                theTable[tempIndex].probed = tempProbed;
                theTable[tempIndex].hashed = hashedValue;
            }

            tempIndex = 0;
            tempProbed = 0;
            tempLineIndex = 0;
            readLineIndex = 0;
            strcpy(tempLine, "\0");


        }

    }
    inFile.close();
    return;
}
```

inFile error on WINDOWS:

```
    Multiple errors reported.

1) Failed to execute MI command:
-var-create - * inFile
Error message from debugger back end:
-var-create: unable to create variable object

2) Failed to execute MI command:
-var-create - * inFile
Error message from debugger back end:
-var-create: unable to create variable object

3) Failed to execute MI command:
-data-evaluate-expression inFile
Error message from debugger back end:
No symbol "inFile" in current context.

4) Failed to execute MI command:
-var-create - * inFile
Error message from debugger back end:
-var-create: unable to create variable object

5) Unable to create variable object
```

Comment: I didn't read your code yet, but you're probably writing outside your arrays and corrupting the data structures for `infile`, or corrupting the `ifstream inFile` object itself.  With a debugger, set up a watchpoint on the value of `inFile`.  If it changes at a line of code that shouldn't touch it (e.g. at a line that writes an array), then you've found the bug.  (Or at least the consequence.  The actual bug might be earlier, and violate assumptions that later code makes.)

Comment: Would this issue be system dependent? Example like I said in original question: works on Windows 10, Eclipse IDE, but not on Linux. @PeterCordes

Comment: It is not necessary that the problem occurs on the `close` statement.  It is probably happening somewhere else where your memory reference is going past the allocated area.  What is `Element300` like?  Is the data being read appropriately?

Comment: @unxnut `Element300` is a c style string with a max of 80 characters. Like I said this function with my program works on Windows but not Linux.

Comment: Different compilers can and will layout the variables differently in memory, so writing past the end of an array will step on something different.  Debug with a watchpoint on inFile, or look at it's value when `.close()` is called.  Or compile with some kind of array bounds-checking.

Comment: Alright I got this on WINDOWS, at the end once it returned. Its in original question. @PeterCordes I don't know what it means at all. Just learning hash tables right now.

Comment: @Programmer12432 The bottom line is that you have arrays, and nowhere at all do you check to see if you index the array in bounds.  Going out-of-bounds of an array is *undefined behavior*.  This means that there is no predictability as to how your program will run -- it can "work" for years, it may crash immediately, it may work on Monday and crash on Tuesday, may work on 1,000 machines and crash on machine 1,001., etc..  So you're lucky that it crashed, and that indicates you more than likely have such a boundary error happening.

Comment: Also, why aren't you using `std::string` instead of char arrays?  Those calls to `strcpy` are not protected if the buffer you're writing to is too small for the source buffer.  With `std::string`, all of those issues go away.

Comment: @Programmer12432 Wherever those errors you just added to the question come from, they don't come from the posted code. No one can guess what problems may exist in the not-posted code. Try to narrow it down to a small, repeatable failure case, and you'll vastly increase your chances of getting a helpful reply.

Comment: Looks like you ran the debugger, but make sure you have Eclipse building a debug load (right-click the project. Select Build Configuration->Set Active->Debug)

Comment: I got it. It was a loop that didn't set that error until i tried to close that inFile.

Answer (score 1):

The loop:

```
while(strcmp(theTable[tempIndex].reserved,tempLine) != 0 && strcmp(theTable[tempIndex].reserved, "\0") != 0)
            {
                tempProbed++;
                tempIndex += 3;

                if(tempIndex > MAX_TABLE)
                {
                    tempIndex = 0;
                }

            }
```

Was somehow going out of bounds. I fixed this by changing the conditions checked and also setting the if statement to `>=` instead of `>`.